# Generic Array List issue with get method (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics, methods

So im creating a generic array list and im having an issue with the get method.  I have it validating the index parameter but I also want it to not use the get method if a parameter that is entered is out of range.  So if someone asks it to get a value at say index 20 when there are only 10 indexes it displays an error message and runs the next code.
Right now it will display my error message and still try to use the get method.

```
public class GenericList<X> {

    // Use an array to create the list
    private X arr[];
    private int size;

    //Constructor for objects of class GSL

    public GenericList(){
        this.newArray();
    }

    // Create a new array

    private void newArray(){
        arr = (X[]) new Object[10];
        size = 0;
    }

    // Expand array

    private void expandArray(){
        X[] arr2;
        arr2 = (X[]) new Object[(int)(arr.length * 1.2)];
        //Copy elements from arr to arr2
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        //Have arr point to new array
        arr = arr2;
    }

    //Return the size of the list

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }


    // Add a value to the list

    public void add(X value){
        if (size == arr.length){
            this.expandArray();
        }
        arr[size] = value;
        size++;
    }

    // Get the value at the specified location in the list

    public X get(int index){
        if (index < 0 || index >= size)
            System.out.println("Index out of bounds");
        return arr[index];
    }
```

Basically if I run this test code:

```
GenericList<Integer> arr = new GenericList();
list.add(27);
list.get(100);

list.get(0);
```

It will create the array, add 27 to the first index, then it will stop and give me the error at list.get(100).
I'm trying to get it to throw an error at that test then skip it and run list.get(0).

Comment: When you're asking a question about an error in your code, it would be smart and helpful to post the full error message, and indicate in your code which line causes it.

Comment: You need to throw an exception if the index is out of bounds. Your code does not do this.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 This method must return a result of type X

 at GenericList.get(GenericList.java:52)

Comment: Of course it will still do this.  All you are currently doing is printing out a statement.  If functions stopped after someone printed something then there would be a whole lot of functions out there that don't work

Comment: I did use this "throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ", Size: " + size);"  In place of the println but it still stops when it tries to use the get method, im trying to get it to display an error and keep going.

Comment: What do you mean it should "keep going"? A non-void method **must** return a value if it completes normally. You decide what that value should be and return it. (Hint: it's probably `null`)

Comment: I have this test code that im running "    GenericList<Integer> arr = new GenericList();
    list.add(27);
    list.get(100);
    
    list.get(0);"    and It will create the array, add 27 to the first index, then it will stop and give me the error at list.get(100). I'm trying to get it to throw an error at that test then skip it and run list.get(0).

Comment: So... you're asking how to [catch an exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing out an error you want to throw an error using the `throw` statement. You probably want an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or something similar. To do this, you should have a check at the beginning of your `get` method:

```
public X get(int index) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{

    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

    return arr[index];
}
```

Then the problem is not with your implementation but in your test code. You want your test code to not stop if `list.get(100);` throws an error:

```
GenericList<Integer> arr = new GenericList();
list.add(27);

try {

    list.get(100);

}
catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println(e);

}

list.get(0);
```